# Append table row contents from TableLayout to StringBuilder

Tags: java, android

I have a table with 3 `TextViews` and 1 Spinner. I am trying to append contents of each row to a `stringBuilder` (the table is a list of invoice items). I ran the code below, but it only appends the last row to the `stringBuilder`. How can I append contents of each row to a `stringBuilder`? Or perhaps how to loop from first row (view) to last and get the contents of each cell?

I tried using the code below:

```
int rowCount = sales_Table.getChildCount();

for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    View view = sales_Table.getChildAt(i);

    t.append("ITEM: " + labelProdName.getText().toString() + '\n');
    t.append("PRICE: " + labelPrice.getText().toString() + '\n');
    t.append("QUANTITY: " + spinner_quantity.getSelectedItem().toString() + '\n');
    t.append("AMOUNT (AED): " + labelTotal.getText().toString() + '\n');
}
```

StringBuilder output (always only the last row)

ITEM: flowers
PRICE: 100
QUANTITY: 1
AMOUNT (AED): 100

Comment: What does your stringbuilder contain exactly, at the end of the operation?

Comment: Its supposed to convert all the row entries into a string and send to the next activity

Comment: Please edit the question to include a text dump representation of exactly what characters are in the stringbuilder at the end of the operation